# Is there a way to define multiple types for a prop in Vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a prop in my Vue component for which I don't know its exact type (it can be of type `Number` or `String`), but there are other props on the same component with a defined type and I don't want to remove their type definition. Is there a way for a prop to accept multiple different types (or type `any`)?

Here is my code:

```js
props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  inputType: {
    type: String,
    default: "text",
  },
  value: {
    type: Any,
    required: true,
  }
}
```

I know that I can declare the props like `props: ['name', 'inputType', 'value']` without defining a type for them, but I was wondering if there is a way to define types for 'name' and 'inputType', but let 'value' accept any type?

I'm using Nuxt v2.15.7

Related links:

[Vue Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that we can define multiple types for a prop using the following syntax; so instead of using any, I fixed the issue by defining all the types that the prop can have:

```js
props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  inputType: {
    type: String,
    default: "text",
  },
  value: {
    type: [String, Number],
    required: true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give it an `undefined` value as mentioned in the following example :

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


Vue.component('my-component', {
template:`<div>{{name}},{{value}}</div>`,
  props:{
  name:String,
  value:undefined
  }
})
new Vue({
      el: '#app',

      data() {
        return {}
      }

    })
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
 <my-component name="test" value="testtt" />
</div>
```